# UIScrollView weird offset -20 top

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a UIViewController whose entire content is just a UIScrollView.

When it loads, it has this weird offset of -20 pixels up top.

Why is that? I can just set it up to zero, but I want to know the cause of this and what's the proper way of dealing with this.

I'm loading it via .xib file.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's making room for the status bar?

Comment: It may have something to do with the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property. I've found that sometimes you can get some weird insets when that's enabled.